# How do I display PHP output next to each other?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to output to be displayed next to each other, anyone knows how I can do this? See screenshot: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkoRl.png)

I could not find any solution.

Part of the code which grabs the information from the database and displays it in $result. I want to display all the results next to each other and not under each other (See screenshot).

````php
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
 
if(isset($_REQUEST["term"])){
    // Prepare a select statement
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE global_name LIKE ?";
    
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_term);
        
        // Set parameters
        $param_term = $_REQUEST["term"] . '%';
        
        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            
            // Check number of rows in the result set
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                // Fetch result rows as an associative array
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                    echo "<span><img style='width:25%;' src='../../"  . $row["image"] . "'></img><p>" . $row["global_name"] . "</p></span>";
                }
            } else{
                echo "<p>No matches found</p>";
            }
        } else{
            echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
        }
    }
     
    // Close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
 
// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>```
````

Comment: @GerarddeVisser it's in my localhost

Comment: Thx for updating with code. I've upvoted to reopen the question now with this clarification.

Comment: @GerarddeVisser thanks, already found my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You very simply set `display: flex` on the container.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  margin: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #369;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```